# The best font for diagrams (use case, uml etc)

Tags: fonts, uml, diagram, use-case

I'm working on my master thesis and i have some diagrams. I'm looking for a font, which can be better for diagrams than "Droid sans mono".....any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html

Comment: looks better than droid sans mono :)

Comment: personally i use schumacher everywhere i can, but it's a bitmap font, so it can only be used on screen.  for editing code, it's great....